# Implementing listener in a new thread

Tags: java, android

i am currently making an `android` app and tried to implement an event listener on a new thread.
This is the implementation of the `onCreate` method of the main activity :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main );

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){
                seek_bar() ;
            }
        }).start();

    }
```

and the implementation of the `seek_bar` method :

```
public void seek_bar()
    {


        seek=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1) ;

        seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(

                new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                         //do somework      

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                     //do some work

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                      //do some work
                    }
                }
        ) ;


    }
```

It works but my question is what could possibly go wrong , and is it a good practice ?

Comment: This code will not run the event listener on the new Thread, all you do is to set the listener. The events will be executed on the UI thread.

Comment: A better question might be: "why do you feel that it is necessary to use two threads to do this?"

Comment: @leoderprofi So what does the new created thread do?

Comment: @MikeRobinson i figured that this is the solution of my [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276398/seekbar-progress-making-the-crosswalk-webview-choppy)

Comment: "Well, if it *works* ..."  But, I don't see how it *actually* does, and, based on @loederprofi's comment #1 above, I predict that it actually *isn't.* The problem here is that now you have two threads, each executing absolutely-independently of one another, both interacting with the same user-interface objects. Are those UI-objects "thread safe?" (Betcha they're not.) And so on. I suggest that you should "bump" your original question in hope that it will be answered. *(I, myself, do not feel qualified to answer it.)* My *gut,* though, tells me that you're most-likely chasing a red herring.

Comment: @MikeRobinson i am only changing the seekbar view inside the thread and never called that view outside that new thread , so far i didn't have any problems , sure it is not the best solution but i can't find another one .